# Use yml configuration instead of standalone.xml

Tags: java, jboss, keycloak

I have lots of microservices and they work in a similar format. What my requirement is to make my **confiuration.yml** files work also for keycloak instead of working with **standalone.xml** (because of my requirements from our customers). I did not see any option that I can override when I check keycloak’s source code since the configuration is done before SPIs.

What I will go in worst scenario is to run some program to convert given configuration.yml to standalone.xml. I appreciate to hear any ideas about how to achieve this. Basically I want to work with YML instead of XML either natively importing something in keycloak or having some converters.

Maybe you can ask why you need this (even for customers), since all of our microservices works like;

```
server:
   port: 80
```

we don’t want to force our clients to learn any different logic to edit our microservices. They will do always in same way to change some basic configurations like above and we can convert these values to proper standalone.xml way. So can I achieve this converter natively extending keycloak or what could be the best option?

Comment: While not having all the choices that you've got in standalone.xml, you can use the keycloak docker image, with `docker-compose` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what settings you want to extract to yml. Standalone.xml allows you to specify configuration values as properties like

```
<socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
```

so you can provide a properties file or prorety value during startup like

```
./standalone.sh --properties=foo.properties -Dfoo=bar
```

but in your case you could store all of this properties in yml and use some startup wrapper for keycloak that will parse your yml and expose all its settings as java properties like:

```
#!/bin/bash 
./standalone.sh $(magictool foo.yml)
```